# Нужна ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Наверное, подобный вопрос уже не раз задавали, но я снова затупил. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая тут: "В отличие от хрупкого алмаза(,) горный хрусталь очень прочный" (речь о том, что твердый алмаз, тем не менее, легко трескается, а вот горный хрусталь — нет).
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, так как оборот при наличии предлога В ОТЛИЧИЕ ОТ практически всегда обособляется, являясь аналогом придаточного предложения. Очень трудно найти вариант, где он не обособляется. Например: Это утро, солнечное и тёплое в отличие от прежних дней, запомнилось особенно (в составе обособленного оборота, сильное управление внутри оборота).

ОТВЕТ 2. Речь идет именно о предлоге В ОТЛИЧИЕ ОТ, который практически всегда относится к обороту с добавочным, а не основным содержанием.

"В отличие от меня он не знает того-то" - в этом предложении я бы поставила запятую. Основное содержание: "он не знает того-то", это самодостаточное сообщение. "В отличие от меня"  - аналог придаточного предложения "если сравнить со мной".

А вот обороты с другими предлогами часто образуют парные варианты, например: По случаю плохой погоды, пароход пришёл позднее обычного. Вылет задержался по случаю большой облачности.

Answer (score 1):

Обороты со словами "в отличие, в зависимости, за неимением, с согласия, во избежание, в соответствии и др." могут обособляться, особенно если эти обороты сильно распространены.(Розенталь". Может и не обособляться: "В отличие от меня он не знает того-то"